# create multiple divs using a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a really simple question but I don't know why it doesn't work.
I have an array with 3 items inside. And I have a container which I would like to insert a number of divs based on the number of items in my array. I used a for loop for this but it is only creating one div. Should it not create 3?

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   var container = document.getElementById("container");
   container.innerHTML = '<div class="box"></div>';
}
```

here is a fiddle to demonstrate further [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfjkta02/)

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=` if you want to add content to the `container` and not replace it.

Comment: You keep **replacing/overwriting**  the innerHTML of your `#container` in every loop step by using `=`. Instead use `append()` or `+=`. Also, you make unnecessary DOM access in every loop step which is a very expensive operation. Move the definition of your `container` variable outside of the loop.

Comment: @Holt The fact that you've suggested `+=` and that your comment has earned upvotes is unsettling to say the least. Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919869/create-multiple-divs-using-a-for-loop/31919934#comment51752599_31919869) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919869/create-multiple-divs-using-a-for-loop/31919934#comment51753872_31919934).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Move `container` out of the loop, it is not required inside it.

Append the innerHTML in each iteration.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   container.innerHTML += '<div class="box"></div>';
}
```

### Edit:

Thanks Canon, for your comments. I also wanted to suggest the same approach as yours, but I got busy in some other work after posting the answer [No excuses :)] Updating the answer:

```
var htmlElements = "";
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   htmlElements += '<div class="box"></div>';
}
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = htmlElements;
```

> This may look like involving more lines of code but this will be more efficient and less error-prone than the previous solution.

Comment: `innerHTML` is parsed everytime you set it. When you modify the `innerHTML` in a loop, the DOM is discarded and the markup re-parsed for every iteration. That's pretty inefficient... and a terrible thing to suggest to someone new to javascript. Either build the entire markup as a string first and set `innerHTML` _once_, or add elements to a document fragment and append the whole fragment.

Comment: @canon, thanks for your comment, I have updated my answer :)

Comment: @sai, please check the edited answer and use it to suit your purpose :)

Comment: Yes I have made the changes, thank you @canon and theghostofc for the clear solution and explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `=` to `+=`

As per the @canon comment, edited answer are below

```
var innerHTMLString = "";  
forloop {
    innerHTMLString += '<div class="box"></div>';
}
document.getElementById("htmlElements").innerHTML = innerHTMLString
```

Comment: Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919869/create-multiple-divs-using-a-for-loop/31919934#comment51753872_31919934).

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
container.innerHTML = '<div class="box"></div>';
```

with this

```
container.innerHTML += '<div class="box"></div>';
```

Comment: Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919869/create-multiple-divs-using-a-for-loop/31919934#comment51753872_31919934).

Comment: @canon, ok got it. But according to the provided code, it was the first what I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create more than one, you must call createElement more than once.

```
d=document.createElement("div");
line into the j loop.
```

If you call appendChild passing in an element that's already in the DOM, it's moved, not copied.

```
window.onload=function()
{
    var i=0;
    var j=0;

    for (i=1; i<=8; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=8; j++)
        {
            if ((i%2!=0 && j%2==0)||(i%2==0 && j%2!=0))
            {
                var d=document.createElement("div");
                document.body.appendChild(d);
                d.className="black";
            }
            else
            {
                var d=document.createElement("div");
                document.body.appendChild(d);
                d.className="white";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Method -

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="box"></div>';
}
```

jQuery Method -

```
foreach(array as value){
    $("#container").append('<div class="box"></div>')
}
```

Comment: Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919869/create-multiple-divs-using-a-for-loop/31919934#comment51753872_31919934).

Answer (score 0):

For further references; what about this approach? :)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="particles">
   <div class="parts"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Cloning divs where particles go in order not to put 300 of them in the markup :)

 const node = document.querySelector(".parts");
 [...Array(300)].forEach(_ =>
 node.parentNode.insertBefore(node.cloneNode(true), node)
 );
```