# How to add multiple div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new for javascript. I have one root div id is "row_logic" itself two div is there. how to increment this root div in below format using javascript?? anyone help.

```
 <div class="row-fluid" id="row_logic">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
       <canvas id="b1" width="600" height="120"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #373737;">
       <canvas id="b2" width="600" height="120"></canvas>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Increment ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Question is unclear. Can you try reconstructing it. Also since you have tagged `twitter-bootstrap-3` you are using Jquery as well in your page. So add that tag if you are open to receive help using Jquery as well.

Comment: You can look this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919869/create-multiple-divs-using-a-for-loop

Comment: can you please tell me that what exactly you want to do? I mean are you want to create a  **row_logic**  div again or the div inside it. (canvas b3..b4..like that?)

Comment: you want to create div element with canvas id like b1,b2,b3,b4  ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4vgrvnn5/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('row_logic').onclick = duplicate;

function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('row_logic');
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // clone
    original.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm using clone() method of jquery and clonning with the class.

```
<a href="#" id="btn">replicate</a>
```

Include jquery here

```
 $('#btn').click(function() {
            alert("Hello");
       $('.row-fluid').clone().insertAfter(".row-fluid");
    });
```

LINK : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rweRKZ